# regex for % | percent after a number

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to extract two-digit numbers and 100 followed by either the percentage sign or the word "percent" and avoid three- or more-digit number and text.

**Example**:

`str <- "text 123-23 45% 1234% 20% 0.2% 100% 123% 2 percent text"`

**Desired output**:

`"45 20 0.2 100 2"`

I know this is far from correct but I have come up with the following:

`str_extract_all(str, "\b\\d+(?:%|percent\b)")`

P.S.: There're many posts regarding similar issues but none were helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***EDIT:*** To add logic NOT to match `123` adding following now.

```
as.numeric(str_extract_all(str, 
"((\\b100)|(\\b[0-9]{1})\\.?[0-9]?)(?=%| *percent)")[[1]])
```

---

Could you please try following(taking a bit adaption from akrun's nice code):

```
as.numeric(str_extract_all(str, 
     "((\\b100)|(\\b[0-9]{1,2}\\.?[0-9]?))(?=%| *percent)")[[1]])
```

Output will be as follows.

```
as.numeric(str_extract_all(str, 
+ "((\\b100)|(\\b[0-9]{1,2}\\.?[0-9]?))(?=%| *percent)")[[1]])
[1]  45.0  20.0   0.2 100.0   2.0
```

Comment: Ravinder ji, I commented only because the OP said that there are cases like 123% in the original dataset

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 it works perfectly except it still catches 123. I edited the string in the original post. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Misha, could you please check my EDIT solution and let me know then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 Works perfectly! Thank you so much for putting so much effort into this!

Comment: DOWN VOTER, code is fixed, please do remove down vote or mention the reason for it too.

Comment: Here's an alternate version that's a bit more succinct: `\\b(100|\\d{1,2}(\\.\\d+)?)(?=%|\\s?percent)`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `str_extract` to extract all numbers before the `%` or word 'percent'

```
as.numeric( str_extract_all(str, "\\b[0-9.]{1,3}(?=%| *percent)")[[1]])
#[1]  45.0  20.0   0.2 100.0   2.0
```

EDIT: as per @Ryan's comment

The above code may not work in some cases.  To avoid that, make the pattern a bit more restrictive

```
out <- as.numeric(str_extract_all(str, 
      "((\\b[0-9]{1,3})|(\\b[0-9]{1,2}\\.?[0-9]?))(?=%| *percent)")[[1]])
out
#[1]  45.0  20.0   0.2 100.0   2.0
```

If there are still more cases that doesn't fit, just do a filter as it would be more efficient to do this instead of having lots of regex patterns

```
out[out <= 100]
```

---

To make it simpler, one or more numbers including dots (`.`) before a `%` sign or the word "percent", extract those numbers, convert it to numeric class and do a filtering

```
out <- as.numeric(str_extract_all(str, "[0-9.]+(?=%| *percent)")[[1]])
out[out <= 100]
```

Comment: Thanks! But how do I extract only two-digit numbers and 100 and not 1234%?

Comment: that wont capture "2  %"  hehehe

Comment: That looks amazing but it's still capturing three-digit numbers that aren't 100%, i.e. 123%. Sorry I didn't include this case in my original post.

Comment: @Misha Could you please include all the cases

Answer (score 0):

You might use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to match 3 parts: either 1 digit optionally followed by a dot and 1-2 digits, or 2 digits optionally followed by a dot and one digit or 100.

Use a negative lookbehind to assert the the match does not start with a dot:

[`(?<!\.)\b(?:\d(?:\.\d{1,2})?|\d{2}(?:\.\d)?|100)(?=%| percent)`](https://regex101.com/r/uaWKnx/1/)

```
str_extract_all(str, "(?<!\\.)\\b(?:\\d(?:\\.\\d{1,2})?|\\d{2}(?:\\.\\d)?|100)(?=%| percent)")[[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I quite understood what you are look for but here's my take:

```
str1 <- str %>% str_replace_all('\\s?percent', '%') %>% 
            str_extract_all('[0-9\\.]+%')

str2 <- str1[[1]] %>% str_remove('%') %>% as.numeric()

str2[str2 <= 100]
##[1]  45.0  20.0   0.2 100.0   2.0
```